# Providing access to HP QC ALM 11.0 for external users outside corp network

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

We have HP QC ALM 11.0 Enterprise edition installed on Windows Server and used by many users across the organisation within corp network. Now we have a requirement for a project to be accessed by external vendors outside the corp network i.e via internet. Can someone provide help if this is possible and required steps?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be simply achieved by opening access for certain group of people. Here you need to host your quality centre site over public ip address where public ip can be purchased from your local ISPs.

In case you just need to share data you have in HP, not the way people using HP inside your corp but transfer/synchronize data to the vendor's 
cloud system or some other alm systems like visual studio tfs online. You can use such cloud based system and run synchronization scripts on your end to transfer/push the data to the customer accessible system. Even you and your vendor can use common cloud based system like visual studio tfs online which most of the companies do. In this case you won't require to manage accesses over internet or don't require to share/host your hp instance over internet. Only data will be shared with the vendor.

Thanks,

Gaurav